# TableView search bar issue (Swift - Firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I really need help with this because i'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue. I'm trying to make my view controller as though when i'm searching for a particular booth name and the value increments from Firebase, only the Booth names that are in my search bar updates instead of reloading the whole booth and updating it(Thus making my search bar useless).

Maybe my screenshots will give you a better idea of the issue. IF you still do not get it, feel free to comment and ask me because i know this is quite complicated. Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

var ref: DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
var postData2 = [String]()
var currentpostDataArray = [String]()
var filteredDataArray = [tableData]()
var tableDataArray = [tableData]()

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpSearchBar()

        ref = Database.database().reference() //set the firebase reference

        // Retrieve the post and listen for changes
        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            currentpostDataArray.removeAll()
            postData2.removeAll()
            tableDataArray.removeAll()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                let value = String(describing: snap.value!)
                let rating = (value as NSString).integerValue
                tableDataArray.append(tableData(boothName: key, boothRating: rating))



            }
            let sortedTableData = tableDataArray.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.boothRating })
            for data in sortedTableData {
                currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

                let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                postData2.append(value)

            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()


        })

    }


    private func setUpSearchBar() {
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
            return currentpostDataArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = currentpostDataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = postData2[indexPath.row] + " ♥"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red;
        return cell
    }



    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        currentpostDataArray.removeAll()
        postData2.removeAll()

        if(searchText.isEmpty)
        {
            let sortedTableData = tableDataArray.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.boothRating })
            for data in sortedTableData {
                currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

                let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                postData2.append(value)
            }
        }
        else {
            let allBooth = tableDataArray.filter{$0.boothName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())}
            let sortedTableData = allBooth.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.boothRating })

            for data in sortedTableData {
                currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

                let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                postData2.append(value)
            }

        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    //Enable "Cancel" button on Search Bar
    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        return true
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = ""
        currentpostDataArray.removeAll()
        postData2.removeAll()
        let sortedTableData = tableDataArray.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.boothRating })
        for data in sortedTableData {
            currentpostDataArray.append(data.boothName)

            let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
            postData2.append(value)

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    }
}

class tableData {
    var boothName: String
    var boothRating: Int
    init(boothName: String, boothRating: Int) {
        self.boothName = boothName
        self.boothRating = boothRating
    }

}
```

SCREENSHOTS: https://ibb.co/cN1XzG https://ibb.co/it3eeG https://ibb.co/bDMAmw

Comment: if you search Booth2 than in filler result only Booth2 appear? right?

Comment: no i could also be "Booth21", "Booth22", "Booth23" so on and so forth

Comment: result you got are same as you want.

Comment: No but if u see from my 3rd image (https://ibb.co/bDMAmw), if the any value increments in firebase, the whole result will reload and update

Comment: I only want the results to update based on my 1st Image (https://ibb.co/cN1XzG) instead of showing all the booths again

Comment: did you user NSPredicate or other to filter value?

Comment: Nope i didn't use NSPredicate